# jQuery Sortable UI Syntax Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, syntax

Im not quite sure what to search for to sort out this problem.

I am getting syntax error with the following code because i have 2 (no idea what to call them)
in the .sortable options. Would you be able to tell me what i have done wrong with this code?

Im using a placeholder and also a connectWith from this page http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets and there doesnt seem to be any examples showing how to write both of them at the same time.

The syntax error is not there when i comment out

```
placeholder: "placeholder-highlighting"
```

or

```
connectWith: ".sortable-content"
```

My code is below:

```
    $(function() {
        $( ".sortable-content" ).sortable({
                placeholder: "placeholder-highlighting"
                connectWith: ".sortable-content"
        });
        $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
    });
```

Bonus points for telling me what they are called!

Comment: you are missing the comma between the 2 options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called options. You are calling the "sortable" method and then saying "use these options instead of the default options (if there are any)".

You need to put a comma between each option!

```
$(function() {
        $( ".sortable-content" ).sortable({
                placeholder: "placeholder-highlighting",
                connectWith: ".sortable-content"
        });
        $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
    });
```

Comment: Now im embarrassed... I was trying everything, brackets, semi colons etc! And all because of one comma.... Thanks